# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: </body> does not close tag <HR>. at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError

Tags: java, sax

I run a dynamic web application via Eclipse and I think that the Tomcat works fine under it, I browsed the servlet from the tomcat server in the Eclipse, the welcome page of the servlet appeared but when I try to access to its differeent functions, I keep getting an error like this:

```
Etat HTTP 500-
type Rapport d'exception HTTP 

message 

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne () qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.oldURLSchema(RestSosFrontend.java:986)
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:482)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)


cause mère 

javax.servlet.ServletException
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:696)
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.oldURLSchema(RestSosFrontend.java:982)
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:482)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)


cause mère 

org.n52.oxf.OXFException
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:696)
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.oldURLSchema(RestSosFrontend.java:982)
org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:482)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

In the console, it outputed:

2011-05-25 12:48:50,000 INFO RestSosFrontend:197 Request URL:<a href="http://localhost:8080/52n-OXF-WS/RESTful/sos/Weather_SOS/observations/ATMOSPHERIC_PRESSURE/urn:ogc:object:feature:OSIRIS-HWS:3d3b239f-7696-4864-9d07-15447eae2b93/urn:ogc:def:property:OGC::BarometricPressure/2008/12/20/02/29/27/01/2011/05/25/12/31/00/02/Measurement" target="_blank">http://localhost:8080/52n-OXF-WS/RES...02/Measurement</a>
2011-05-25 12:49:39,921 ERROR [REST-SOS]:253 "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet REST-SOS a généré une exception
org.n52.oxf.OXFException
at org.n52.oxf.feature.sos.SOSObservationStore.unmarshalFeatures100(SOSObservationStore.java:114)
at org.n52.oxf.feature.sos.SOSObservationStore.unmarshalFeatures(SOSObservationStore.java:63)
at org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.showResultsInPreferredMIMEType(RestSosFrontend.java:669)
at org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.oldURLSchema(RestSosFrontend.java:982)
at org.n52.oxf.rest.sos.RestSosFrontend.doGet(RestSosFrontend.java:482)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:663)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: </body> does not close tag <HR>.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3471)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at net.opengis.om.x10.ObservationCollectionDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.n52.oxf.feature.sos.SOSObservationStore.unmarshalFeatures100(SOSObservationStore.java:100)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: </body> does not close tag <HR>.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
... 25 more
```

Please, what's the problem? How can I resolve it? I searched in the net about this problem but have not found a solution that works for me.

Thanks for your prompt answer that I really really need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the very bottom of the trace. The root cause of the exception is the most important part.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: </body> does not close tag <HR>.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportFatalError(Piccolo.java:1038)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:723)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
... 25 more
```

The `<HR>` is not XML well formed. In XML you need to close all tags. Replace `<HR>` by `<hr/>`.

Comment: Thnx Balus for your prompt response, but where can I found this command (HR)?

Comment: It's not a command. It's a HTML tag. Do a global file search in your web project.

Comment: I mean in which file?web.xml for example?

Comment: The one whatever your servlet is attempting to parse. Impossible to tell based on the as far given information, but it's definitely not `web.xml` or something, but a HTML file which is not well formed XML. It has a `<HR>` before a `</body>`. Do a global file search in your web project.

Comment: Hi again Balus, I will tell You what I m going to do: I have an application in SVN that I should test it. for that I use Eclipse to run it and apache tocat 5.5.12. I ran tha project and eclipse created the .class files after compilation. Then I copied the .war into the webapp folder of the tomcat. Then I execute the project as application web dynamic, and browse it via apache server in the eclipse. But when I ran it, the error mentionned above has been appeared.

Comment: In addition, now when I try to browse it again, I didn't find the application, just there are a white page!!  what do You think it's happened? are there somethings wrong in my installation? Thnx for your help that I really need.

Answer (score 0):

Either your deployment is incorrect or the connection URL is wrong.  If the servlet is running, you aren't pointing to it properly.

Comment: Thnx Duffy for your response but what You mean by pointing to it properly Plz? the servlet is runned fine, some of its links work good, but there are others that when I access to them, they outputed this error.